# Android Geofence events not being called while running Foreground Service

Tags: android, geolocation, broadcastreceiver, android-geofence, foreground-service

I'm working on a commute tracking application that automatically records users commutes between Geofences. The app must meet the following requirements:

- Respond to geofence enter and exit events while the app is both in use or closed
- When a user transitions from idle to walking/biking/driving etc, start recording user location
- When a user transitions from walking/biking/driving etc to idle, stop recording user location
- On a geofence exit event, begin recording the commute
- On a geofence enter event, end and record the commute

My current set-up is as follows:

- A `GeofenceBroadcastReceiver` to listen for geofence enter/exit events
- A `GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService` for processing the geofence events from the `GeofenceBroadcastReceiver`
- A `ActivityTransitionsBroadcastReceiver` that processes motion events from the Android Activity Transitions API, and kicks off a `LocationUpdateForegroundService`
- A `LocationUpdateForegroundService` that tracks user location updates, and manages the foreground service so that everything continues to work when the app isn't "open"

The `ActivityTransitionsBroadcastReceiver` and the `LocationUpdateForegroundService` work great. When the user begins walking/biking etc the app recognizes it and the foreground service is started as expected, and stops when the user transitions back to being idle.

The main problem is Geofence enter/exit events are highly variable in their delivery. I've read up on the background execution limits of geofencing event in modern OS levels, and by having the app running in a `ForegroundService` whenever the user is actually in motion, I expected the geofence events to be delivered timely and reliably.

Can anyone confirm that I'm doing something very wrong here? Is my high level logic/set-up reasonable? I can post code if anyone thinks I would be helpful.

Thank you.